# PCL XL Error on HP Printer

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

I wanted to print something but my HP Laserjet 1200 printer gave me this error printed out:

```
PCL XL error  
    Subsystem: KERNEL  
    Error:     IllegalTag  
    Operator:  0x34  
    Position:  114307
```

Last time I tried to print something, everything worked fine.

I use Linux Mint 10, with KDE4.6. My printer driver is included in the HPLIP package for Ubuntu.

After a bit research on the web, I have found that this is quite a common error for HP printers but I can only find solutions for Windows.

Does anyone know how I can get it working?

Answer (score 0):

The PCL XL Error typically shows up when a user tries to send multiple documents for printing.

One of the primary reasons why this problem occurs is a corrupted printer driver. In some instances, the printer settings can also cause the error to show up.